# Arranging numbers in a grid

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I have a $n \times m$ matrix $M$ and a permutation of sequence $P$ of numbers from $1$ to $n$.

I have to fill the matrix using numbers $1$ to $n \times m$ in such a way that for each row $i$, the function $f(i) > 0.5$ where:

$f(i)$ is the probability that a number chosen randomly from row $i$ will be greater than a number chosen randomly from row $P[i]$. ($i$'s corresponding row according to permutation.)

For an example, let $n=3$,$m=3$,$P=[3, 1, 2]$ and $M=$

```
2 6 7
3 4 8 
1 5 9
```

According to the given permutation, you will have to compare the number chosen from 1st row with 3rd row and similarly.

In the given matrix number are arranged in such a way that $f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = 5/9$.
Observe that there are 5 pairs in the Cartesian product $\{2,6,7\}\times\{1,5,9\}$ which the first element is larger than the second.

My question is how to construct such a matrix provided $n,m,P$ as input?

Comment: @Rebecca thanks a lot for your help....I have updated the problem statement with mathematical notation...let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: Thanks!  That's clear to me now.  [I'll delete my previous comment.]  (This will also require the permutation not having fixed points nor $2$-cycles.)

Comment: yes ...correct...but I am unable to figure out the general case.

Comment: I think the smallest matrix for which an assignment is possible is of size 3*3,now if I can find a way of assignment for it, then for higher order matrix, there may be a way out to find solution in recursive manner...

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/28296/755 (and on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24643001/781723).